# Models.Link.getType in Spotify Apps API V1.0.0

Tags: api, model, spotify

In pre V1.0 Spotify Apps API you could do...

```
var uri_type = models.Link.getType(playlist_uri); // returns 5 (number)
```

To find out if a URI is a Track, Playlist, Album etc...
http://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/0.1/506827d4e4.html

But I don't see anything similar in V1.0.0 of the apps API.
https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/

Anyone know if something similar is in the new API?

Cheers

Comment: What are you using this for? If you need to it to determine the type in order to know what type to use when loading the URI (e.g. Playlist.fromURI, Artist.fromURI), you could use [models.fromURI(String uri)](http://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/models.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need it to determine the type in order to know what type to use when loading the URI (e.g. Playlist.fromURI, Artist.fromURI), you could use [models.fromURI(String uri)](http://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/models.html).

Furthermore, if you'd like to know exactly which type was loaded, you can check the constructor.name property of the loaded object. For example,

```
require(['$api/models'], function(models) {
   var loadable = models.fromURI("spotify:artist:18iQQOuyGlHunPVzmoLY20");
   console.log(loadable.constructor.name);
});
```